# GetRolesForUser returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roleprovider

In the background of my mvc 4 application i am running a scheduler that does some tasks.
When i want to get the roles from a specific user the functions returns a nullreference exception.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Web.dll
```

The function does work with a normal request, but not outside a normal http request.

Why is GetRolesForUser not working outside a normal request (assuming that is the problem) and how can i fix it?

Note: Im using the parameter username, the user exists and has a role.

Im using the DefaultMembershipProvider.

Code:

```
   public static string GetUserRoleByUsername(string username)
    {
        return System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(username).First();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

I have fixed it by initializing the roleProvider, i am not sure why i need to initialize it.
Any ideas why i have to do this?

```
var roleProvider = System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider;
```

Comment: Is User.Identity.Name initialized?

Comment: No its not, im using the GetRolesForUser function outside the controller, so the httpcontext is empty. Im not getting the roles from the logged in user, just a random user.